# Karma Wordpress template: Facebook icon for comments overlaps the default icon

Tags: facebook, wordpress, comments

If your look at this screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/1J3m2e2x1G1z, you'll notice that the facebook iframe element overwrites the Karma comment bubble. Could anybody help me with either removing the bubble alltogether of with removing the facebook element?
thanks

Comment: Please show the code that you've used to get this to happen.

Comment: Dear Ryan, I'm not a programmer, could you be more specific? What I can tell that I have installed the official Facebook plugin (Version 1.0.2). I had then activated the 'comments' option. It is then that I saw the overwriting of the karma bubble comment. see also http://indekerk.be/media/blog-2/.

Comment: In the meantime I have found out there were css stylesheets for this plugin backend and I have removed the following lines:  return $output;
}  
function fb_get_comments_count() {
  return '<iframe src="' . ( is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http' ) . '://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?' . http_build_query( array( 'href' => get_permalink(), 'permalink' => 1 ) ) . '" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:130px; height:16px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
}

function fb_comments_automatic($content) {
 global $post;

Comment: this FB overwriting is gone now but also the normal link to the comments.

Comment: You are using a Premium Template, which offers support if you aren't a  cheapscate ;)

Comment: And also, editing core code is a not done practice. It's best to create a Child Theme, copy the core files you want to edit and edit them here.

Comment: Thanks, yes idd a payed premium template...but since this is a facebook plugin I presumed that this is the first place to look for answers. Your second comment, is there a link to an easy how-to please?

Comment: Please put your code inside the question, where it can be formatted, not inside a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be fixed pretty easily with css. If you have a link to the site I can take a look at it and tell you what you need to add to your stylesheet. Also, t.thielemans is right, it would be best set up a child theme ([Not nearly as complicated as it sounds](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/12/creating-your-first-wordpress-child-theme/)) which would prevent the changes from going away if you update your theme.